# Number of indecomosbale $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ modules finite

Tags: reference-request, representation-theory

Is there a theorem like those of Jones, which tells if the number of different $\mathbb{Z}_p[G]$ modules is finite, where $G$ is a finite group and $\mathbb{Z}_l$ the $p$-adic ring?

Comment: Jones's paper seems to handle this already.

Comment: Do you mean his original work? I just have a version of his theorem for $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ modules.

Comment: Yes, his published paper. Apparently actually Heller and Reiner already did this in their work. Reiner explains it in his review of a russian version of their work (the Russian and Western schools of group theory did not talk enough during this time). http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=166273

Comment: At any rate, it is not hard to give a proof using Prop 7 down to the end of Jones's paper, and Reiner outlines a similar proof in his review.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactlly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Heller and Reiner proved this in the early 60s.

**Proposition:** $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[G]$ has finitely many indecomposable representations if and only if $G$ has a cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup of order at most $p^2$.

Higman (1954) proves the corresponding classification for fields of characteristic $p$ (finitely many indecomposable modules iff Sylow $p$-subgroup is cyclic). In particular, his technique of inducing from a Sylow to the whole group (which we learn about in terms of Green's theory of “sources”) applies to $p$-adic representations as well: If $M$ is an indecomposable $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[G]$ module, then there is some indecomposable $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[P]$ summand $V$ of $M_P$ ($P$ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$) so that $M$ is a direct summand of the induced module $V^G$. In particular, if the number of indecomposable $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[P]$ modules is finite, so is the number of indecomposable $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[G]$ modules. Similarly the converse holds, so it suffices to consider $p$-groups only. I believe Higman already settles the case of non-cyclic $p$-groups, but Reiner credits the following:

Borevič–Faddeev (1959) proved (though I have not verified) that if $G$ has a non-cyclic Sylow $p$-subgroup, then $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[G]$ has infinitely many indecomposable representations. This is not surprising as $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[G]$ has infinitely many indecomposable modules, and they all lift to $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[G]$.

Heller–Reiner (1962), theorems 2.6 and 3.1, show that if $G$ is cyclic of order $p$ or $p^2$, then $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[G]$ has exactly $3$ or $4p+1$ (respectively) indecomposable representations. The case of order $p$ is due to Diederichsen (1940).

Heller-Reiner (1963), theorem page 327, show that if $G$ is cyclic of order $p^3$ then $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[G]$ has infinitely many indecomposable representations. Since every indecomposable $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[G/N]$ is an indecomposable $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[G]$ representation, it follows that if $G$ is cyclic of order $p^k$ for any $k \geq 3$, then $\hat{\mathbb{Z}}_p[G]$ has infinitely many indecomposable representations.

This completes the proof for integral $p$-adic representations. The proof for (rational) integral representations was completed by Jones (1963), results from his dissertation.

- Diederichsen, Fritz-Erdmann
  “Über die Ausreduktion ganzzahliger Gruppendarstellungen bei arithmetischer Äquivalenz.”
  Abh. Math. Sem. Hansischen Univ. 13, (1940). 357–412.
  MR[2133](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2133)
- Higman, D. G.
  “Indecomposable representations at characteristic $p$.”
  Duke Math. J. 21, (1954). 377–381
  MR[67896](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=67896)
  DOI:[10.1215/S0012-7094-54-02138-9](http://dx.doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-54-02138-9)
- Borevič, Z. I.; Faddeev, D. K.
  “Theory of homology in groups II,”
  Proc. Leningrad Univ., 14 (1959) no 7, 72-87.
  ZBL[0171.28301](http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/en/search/?q=an:0171.28301)
  MR[106234](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=106234)
- Heller, A.; Reiner, I.
  “Representations of cyclic groups in rings of integers. I.”
  Ann. of Math. (2) 76 (1962) 73–92.
  MR[140575](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=140575) DOI:[10.2307/1970266](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1970266)
- Heller, A.; Reiner, I.
  “Representations of cyclic groups in rings of integers. II.”
  Ann. of Math. (2) 77 (1963) 318–328.
  MR[144980](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=144980)
  DOI:[10.2307/1970218](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1970218)
- Jones, Alfredo
  “Groups with a finite number of indecomposable integral representations.”
  Michigan Math. J. 10 (1963) 257–261. 
  MR[153737](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=153737)
  DOI:[10.1307/mmj/1028998908](http://dx.doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1028998908)